# Как связать зависимые между собой инпуты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, input, jinja2

Есть два `input`, к которым прикреплены `datalist`:

```
<input list="curr-name-list" type="text" name="iso_name" class="form-control" id="iso-name" placeholder="Euro*" title="Type here international name of currency" required>
    <datalist id="curr-name-list">
      {% for currency in currencies %}
        <option data-iso-id ="{{ currency.iso_id }}" value="{{ currency.name}}">{{ currency.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
```

Конструкция `{% something %}` и `{{ another_something }}` - синтаксис `jinja`. 
К этому инпуту прикреплен список с именами валют(Например, `Euro`, `US Dollar` etc.) К каждому `option` даю `data` аттрибут с `iso` номером валюты. Похожая конструкция со вторым инпутом:

```
<input list="iso-code-list" type="text" class="form-control" name="iso_code" id="iso-code" placeholder="EUR*" title="Type here ISO code" required>
  <datalist id="iso-code-list">
    {% for currency in currencies %}
      <option data-iso-id ="{{ currency.iso_id }}" value="{{ currency.iso_code}}">{{ currency.iso_code}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
```

Итак, после рендеринга имею два инпута, к каждому прикреплен `datalist`. Суть вопроса: как при заполнении одного инпута вставить соответствующее значение во второй? Не обязательно оперировать `data-iso-id`, это скажем так, мой набросок. Заранее спасибо за помощь.